# replacing a input value

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way to replace a string as having & in the textarea breaks the script as it thinks its another & parameter?

```
function doRequest(){
var str = $('textarea#tr').val();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "index.php?sd=t",
   data: "txt="+str.replace(/&/g, "and"),
   success: function(){
        $("div").css('color','red');
        $("div").text('Saved');
        $("div").fadeTo(800,1);
        $("div").animate({backgroundColor:'#000000'}, 200);
        $("div").animate({backgroundColor:'#FFFF90'}, 400);
        stre = false;
   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your data as an object and let jQuery serialize it, like this:

```
data: {txt: str},
```

Note this won't put the word "and", it'll escape it, leaving `%26`.

[What *actually* happens under the covers](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L510) is calling [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), like this:

```
data: "txt="+encodeURIComponent(str),
```

I'd go with the first method, I'm just showing what is happening underneath for better understanding of how the encoding works.

Comment: the reason of having txt is so that from within php i use $_GET['txt'], if i remove this to let jquery serialize what will the get request be called?

Comment: @Slug - It'll still be called `txt`, whatever the property name is in the object, that's what the parameter's called on the GET request, e.g. this will still serialize to  "txt=something", you can test/see it with `alert($.param({txt: str}))`, that's what gets called under the covers  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
data: { txt: $('textarea#tr').val() }
```